# how to get schedule details from outlook

Tags: php

I sent schedule/appointment via outlook to some email address.
I want to use php in order to open the email end get the schedule/appointment  information, such as - when the appointment begin.

The problem is that the header of this email contain only info about the sender and the email subject. nothing about the appointment time.

the body contain free text with all the data I need. but is a free text (without tags)

how can I get the appointment details?

here is example of the body:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN VERSION:2.0 METHOD:REQUEST X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE BEGIN:VEVENT ATTENDEE;CN=calendar@peleg.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:calendar@peleg.com CLASS:PUBLIC CREATED:20141021T101129Z DESCRIPTION:When: ‎יום שלישי 28 אוקטובר 2014 10:00 עד 11 :30 (UTC+02:00) ירושלים.\nWhere: תל אביב\n\nNote: The GMT offset above does not reflect daylight saving time adjustments.\n\n*~* ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*\n\nבדיקה לשליחת זימון\nלאתר PELEG\ n\n\n DTEND:20141028T093000Z DTSTAMP:20141021T101129Z DTSTART:20141028T080000Z LAST-MODIFIED:20141021T101129Z LOCATION:תל אביב ORGANIZER;CN="Roi ":mailto:roi@peleg.com PRIORITY:5 SEQUENCE:0 SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=he:test calendar TRANSP:OPAQUE UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000C092F08630EDCF01000000000000000 01000000024248BF586C06D40AC4581E1391079F9 X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n

When: ‎&rlm\;יום שלישי 28 < FONT FACE="Arial (Hebrew)">אוקטובר 2014 10:00 עד 11:30 (UTC+02:00 &rlm\;)< SPAN LANG="en-us"> יר ושלים.
\n\n
```

Answer (score 0):

The Format **VCalendar** is a parsable file format. There even are public available libraries for this format. So either use one of them (Google vCalendar) or parse it yourself:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#vCalendar_1.0

Hint: When replacing those `\n` with real line breaks, that top text line looks very easy to parse:

```
//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN VERSION:2.0 METHOD:REQUEST X-MS-OLK-    FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE BEGIN:VEVENT ATTENDEE;CN=calendar@peleg.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:calendar@peleg.com CLASS:PUBLIC CREATED:20141021T101129Z DESCRIPTION:When: ‎יום שלישי 28 אוקטובר 2014 10:00 עד 11 :30 (UTC+02:00) ירושלים.
Where: תל אביב

Note: The GMT offset above does not reflect daylight saving time adjustments.

*~* ~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*

בדיקה לשליחת זימון
לאתר PELEG\ n

 DTEND:20141028T093000Z DTSTAMP:20141021T101129Z DTSTART:20141028T080000Z LAST-MODIFIED:20141021T101129Z LOCATION:תל אביב ORGANIZER;CN="Roi ":mailto:roi@peleg.com PRIORITY:5 SEQUENCE:0 SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=he:test calendar TRANSP:OPAQUE UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000C092F08630EDCF01000000000000000 01000000024248BF586C06D40AC4581E1391079F9 X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:

When: ‎&rlm\;יום שלישי 28 < FONT FACE="Arial (Hebrew)">אוקטובר 2014 10:00 עד 11:30 (UTC+02:00 &rlm\;)< SPAN LANG="en-us"> יר ושלים.
```